Substation supplies with touching MSBs
On this site we have the below setup:
We have 3 x main switchboards fed via 3 x separate transformers that are existing, this existing MSB has a connecting earth bar only and no neutral connecting bar as the transformers are treated as completely separate supplies.
We have built 3 x new main switchboards in a new location and these 3 x separate supplies are to be fed via a new route to these 3 x new switchboards. Each MSB has a common earth bar but no common neutral as per the existing MSB.
The intention throughout construction was to install a carried earthing system to the sub-station with the consumer mains cables to each transformer and form the MEN within the sub-station which would create the CMEN system. Being a back to back sharing same roof line it is widely known and used that the CMEN system is adopted in such an installation.
AUSNET have since retracted the Carried earthing solution although the sub is back to back and have advised that the MEN will not be located at the sub and must be located within the MSBs, the item I need clarification on is if this is the case we are required to have to install 3 x MENS within each switchboard as each supply is essentially treated as one x MSB in sections.
Now the method of install is to install 3 x MEN's within each of the 3 x MSBs and then install one x earth stake with a 120 mm2 earth fed via one of the MSBs as the main earthing conductor as the MSBs have the common earth bar throughout.

I think you should explain your TLA's. MSB might mean Most Significant Bit. AUSNET, MEN and CMEN is unknown to me, at least.
